# How to specify input and output dimensions

Tags: keras

I want to use deep learning and I have a 5000 training examples.

Each example has dimensions 4 x 12. 
And **each** output example's dimension will be 16 x 4.

How do I specify this in Keras?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((16, 4), input_shape=(4,12)))
model.add(Dense())
```

Comment: You're not very eager to read documentation and tutorials and to google, are you?